# Problems with encoding in PHP functions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to build an URL from a string, that I get with webcrawler. I have managed to create a crawler, but I can't make an URL string... I have managed to find out that PHP function preg_match_all messes up my result. This is what I have:

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $matches); 
foreach ($matches[1] as $value) {
     $termsArray[] = $this->createUrl($value);
}
```

The preg_match_all function returns the correct string but, I guess, the encoding is wrong... And the createUrl function looks lite this:

```
private function createLikitUrl($term)
    {
    $ltSymbolsArray = array(
              'a1' => 'ą',
              'c2' => 'č',
              'e1' => 'ę',
              'e2' => 'ė',
              'i1' => 'į',
              's2' => 'š',
              'u1' => 'ų',
              'u2' => 'ū',
              'z2' => 'ž',
              '_' => ' '
          );
          $chars = preg_split("//u", $term, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
          $urlStr = '';
          foreach ($chars as $value) {
            foreach ($ltSymbolsArray as $key => $replacement) {
              if ($value == $replacement) {
                $value = $key;
              }
            }
            $urlStr .= $value;
          }
}
```

The problem is that preg_split returns the same string that I pass as $term variable when preg_match_all is used with a string that has multibyte symbols. If I pass a string to the createUrl function without using preg_match_all, then it works perfectly. My guess is that I am missing unicode modifier in preg_match_all pattern, but I have hard time on writting regular expressions.

Anny help would be apreciated.

Comment: Where are your delimiters for your preg_split call?

Comment: try to add `u` to preg_match_all regexp like `/"([^"]+)"/u`

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: Before the preg match I have a big js array with some words in it from here: [link](http://www.likit.lt/term/sarasas.js). After the preg match the input is values of the js array and in the createUrl function the words should be splitted by letters and multibyte symbols should be replaced. If I use preg_match_all the split only works with values that hasn't got any multibyte symbols...  Ilya Bursov, if I add u at the end of the regexp, I get null...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your request, but I tried your script and it works pretty fine, except that you need to add a `return $urlStr;` at the end of the function.
And it has to be renamed `createUrl`.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, it is only a part of the code. I can't understand... If I use this function with a string without the preg_match_all then it works fine, but if I use preg match with the same string, the preg_split returns me the same (unsplitted) string... This happens only if the string has anny multibyte symbols. If it hasn't,the split works fine.

Comment: @Kęstutis: That's really strange, as I said, it works fine for me, the diacritic chars are well transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found a solution. If anyone will come across to this problem, this should help. As I thought, there was a problem with encoding. I just added one line of code before the preg_match_all that solved the problem:

```
$matches = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-13');
```

Cheers! :)